# Convert javascript datetime into php datetime

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime

I want to convert javascript date `Mon Jun 23 2014 16:17:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` into PHP datetime. I tried

`echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($expire_time));`

where `$expire_time` is `Mon Jun 23 2014 16:17:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` but it is giving  `1970-01-01 12:00:00`.

Please help.

Comment: Not really a duplicate as the other question mentions a specific format from a function, not an RFC 3339 output from Javascript Date.

Comment: Instead of relying to javascript `toString`, you should use `toISOString`to get a standard date format (which is well recognized by php `strtotime`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(India Standard Time)` causes the problem with parsing, so you need to remove it from the string before calling `date()`. You can use something like:

```
$expire_time = 'Mon Jun 23 2014 16:17:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
$expire_time = substr($expire_time, 0, strpos($expire_time, '('));

echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($expire_time));
```